# Create a class that creates Function objects as instance using es6 class syntax

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to create a class that instantiates functions with methods on it's prototype? I am trying to convert code from prototype structure to using the es6 class syntax. Here is a contrived and over simplified example of the starting point

```
function createFun(init) {
  function fun(newDats) {
    this.data = newDats;
    // create universe
  }
  function internalMethod() {
  }
  fun.data = init;
  fun.aMethod = function () {
    internalMethod();
  }
  assign(fun, AnExtendableClass.prototype);
  return fun;
}

// and can be used as such
fun = createFun('first');
fun('second');
fun.aMethod();
fun.methodFromExtendableClass('third')
```

And this is what I have tried

```
class Fun extend AnExtendableClass {
   constructor(init) {
     super();
     this.data = init;
     function fun(newDats) {
       this.data = newDatas;
       //create universe
     }
     assign(fun, this);
     return fun;
   }

   aMethod() {
   }
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work and function with no methods in return.

Comment: What's the point of using a class for creating something that is not an instance of itself? Having a function that produces the class seems to be much more reasonable. It makes sense to turn `Fun` into a class. It doesn't make sense to turn `createFun` into a class.

Comment: @FelixKling Turning Fun into a class is what I am trying to accomplish. createFun is just a class instantiator. I have other create functions that I am converting to straight classes successfully but this one class is a function object with methods and that is giving me issues.

Comment: @JLRishe assign is equivalent to Object.assign or _.assign

Comment: I see. I didn't notice first that you where merging `OtherConstr.prototype` into `Fun`. Just keep that line, see my answer.

Comment: I guess it comes back to my first comment again. It seems you actually want to replace `createFunc` with a class, not `Fun`. As I said, that doesn't make sense. Judging from the use case, nothing in this example should (or can be) converted to classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a class that instantiates functions with methods on it's prototype?

Yes, with ES6 it is possible to subclass `Function` - however, that's not exactly nice, as the constructor expects code strings:

```
class Fun {
    constructor() {
        super("newDats", `
            this.data = newDats;
            // create universe
        `)
    }
    data() { }
    aMethod() { }
}

let fun = new Fun;
fun(…);
fun.aMethod(…);
```

> I am trying to convert code from prototype structure to using the es6 class syntax. Here is a contrived and over simplified example of the starting point

Don't use the `class` syntax for that. The new syntax is very limited, and should only be used for standard class declarations. If you do anything weird - and returning functions from the constructor, copying methods from other classes, assigning static properties and using internal methods is definitely weird in this regard - then go use the "old", explicit way. The new `Reflect.setPrototypeOf` is giving you additional freedom here.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi I guess it makes more sense to leave this bit of code as it is. Being able to create functions from classes seems like something that should be do-able in javascript but I guess that is not within the intention of this syntax.