# Making `obj.someMethod()` available as `obj()` without preventing `obj` from behaving as a normal instance

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, ecmascript-6, prototypal-inheritance

To avoid misunderstanding, let's agree on the meaning of certain words first. The following meanings are not universally accepted ones, I only suggest them as a context for this question.

- **function** -- an instance of `Function`. It has a *procedure* associated with it.
- **object** -- an instance of any other class. Does not have a procedure associated with it.
- **procedure** -- a block of code that can be executed. In JS procedures  can only be found associated with *functions*.
- **method** -- a function that is stored in a property of another object. Methods execute in their host objects' contexts.

In JavaScript it is common that *objects* are customized with properties and methods, while *functions* don't. In other words, if you see this in code:

```
foo.bar   // Accessing a property on an instance
foo.baz() // Calling a method on an instance
```

then `foo` is almost certainly an *object* and not a *function*.

But technically *functions* are no different from *objects* (in fact, *functions* in JS are considered to be *objects*, it's just me distinguishing them for clarity).

And if you do this:

```
const foo = function () { /*...*/ }
foo()     // Calling the function's procedure
foo.bar   // Accessing a property on the function
foo.baz() // Calling a method on the function
```

...it will work just fine.

I would like to introduce two more terms so that you can understand what I mean. I'm not trying to alter the rules of JavaScript here, just want to be understood.

- **function-object** -- an *function* that is used as an *object*: has its own properties and/or methods.
- **main method** -- the procedure of a *function-object* itself, as opposed to methods stored as properties on a *function-object*.

Many JS libraries offer *function-objects*, for example jQuery and LoDash. I. e. you can do both `$()` and `$.map()`.

---

Okay, now to the matter.

I would like to be able to create my own *function-objects* with the following requirements:

1. I should be able to use the ES2015 `class` declaration to describe the class of my *function-object*. Or at least the way of describing the class should be convenient enough. Imperatively assigning properties and methods to a *function* is not convenient.
2. The *main method* of my *function object* should execute in the same context as its other *methods*.
3. The *main method* and other *methods* should be bound to the same instance. For example if I have a *main method* and a normal *method* that both do `console.log(this.foo)`, then assigning to `myFunctionObject.foo` should modify the behavior of both the main mehtod and the other method.

In other words, I want to be able to do this:

```
class Foo {
  constructor   () { this.bar = 'Bar'; }
  mainMethod    () { console.log(this.bar); }
  anotherMethod () { console.log(this.bar); }
}
```

...but an instance of `Foo` should have `foo.mainMethod()` available simply as `foo()`.

And doing `foo.bar = 'Quux'` should modify the behavior of both `foo()` and `foo.anotherMethod()`.

Maybe there's a way to achieve it with `class Foo extends Function`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a class that creates Function objects as instance using es6 class syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29248034/1048572)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't override anything, `new Foo` will return an object type, not a function type. You can potentially do

```
class Foo {
  constructor(){
    const foo = () => foo.mainMethod();
    Object.setPrototypeOf(foo, this);

    foo.bar = 'Bar';

    return foo;
  }
  mainMethod    () { console.log(this.bar); }
  anotherMethod () { console.log(this.bar); }
}
```

so that `new Foo` will return a function that has explicitly been set up so that it returns a function with the proper prototype chain configuration. Note that I'm explicitly setting `foo.bar` instead of `this.bar` so that `hasOwnProperty` will still work as expected throughout the code.

You could also work around this by setting it up via a base class, e.g.

```
class CallableClass {
  constructor(callback){
      const fn = (...args) => callback(...args);
      Object.setPrototypeOf(fn, this);
      return fn;
  }
}

class Foo extends CallableClass {
  constructor(){
    super(() => this.mainMethod());
    this.bar = 'Bar';
  }
  mainMethod    () { console.log(this.bar); }
  anotherMethod () { console.log(this.bar); }
}
```

I'm writing this in real ES6, but you'll have to change the rest/spread args to a normal function if you want it to work in Node v4. e.g.

```
const foo = function(){ callback.apply(undefined, arguments); };
```

The downside to both of these approaches is that they rely on `Object.setPrototypeOf`, which does not work in IE<=10, so it will depend what support you need. The general understanding is that `Object.setPrototypeOf` is also very slow, so I'm not sure you have a ton of options here.

The main alternative that ES6 provides for this case would be Proxies, but they are not at all well supported yet.

Comment: (*The dowside to both...*) and the impact on performance of using [`.setPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf).

Comment: I would recommend `Object.setPrototypeOf(foo, Object.getPrototypeOf(this))` so that not every function has its own prototype. Or more explicitly, `Object.setPrototypeOf(foo, new.target.prototype)`.

Comment: When I call `new Foo()()` it logs `undefined` instead of `Bar`.

Comment: @torazaburo Quite right, my mistake for changing something without testing it :) Had `this.mainMethod()` instead of `foo.mainMethod()` in the arrow function of the first example.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way to add a [[Call]] method to an existing object.

Proxies might seem a potential solution, but the problems are that the proxy object is a different object than the [[ProxyHandler]], and that [the [[ProxyHandler]] must already have a [[Call]] method in order to be able to set an `"apply"` trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32360219/1529630).

Therefore, the only viable solution is creating a new function with the desired [[Call]], replace its [[Prototype]], and make the constructor return that function instead of the "real" instance.

```js
class Foo {
  constructor   () {
    var instance = function(){ return instance.mainMethod(); };
    Object.setPrototypeOf(instance, Foo.prototype);
    return Object.assign(instance, {bar: 'Bar'});
  }
  mainMethod    () { console.log(this.bar); }
  anotherMethod () { console.log(this.bar); }
}
```

Comment: Uhm, I should have refreshed the page before answering, I didn't see a similar answer appeared after I opened this page some hours ago. Well, I will leave mine because the other doesn't work.